# Ubuntu and Visual Studio Code: C++ Intellisense not working right

Tags: c++, json, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have recently made the switch from Sublime Text to Visual Studio Code. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The problem i'm not  able to fix is to get Intellisense working right. I have the C/C++ extension installed.

The JSON properties file looks like that:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "/usr/include/c++/5",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include/c++/5",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include/*"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
]
```

}

I tried Intellisense with a simple program like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<int> vec;

return 0;
```

}

Everytime i type vec (and press STRG+SPACE for Intellisense) i get the right response from Intellise showing a lot of suggestions for vector.

The problem i now have is, that when i enter vec. i would expect the class methods to be shown from Intellisense. But i don't get the right suggestions.

For example if i enter vec.pu (and press STRG+SPACE for Intellisense) i would expect to get a suggestion for the push_back() method, which i don't get.

Does someone have a fix for that or experienced the same problem?

I'm using the following c++ version:
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

The c++ header files are located there you would expect them:

/usr/include/c++

There are two folders in here:

/usr/include/c++/5

and:

/usr/include/c++/5.4.0

The JSON File hast the first folder referenced...i guess thats correct. I tried to add the second folder to the JSON file. But that did not fix the problem. 
Intellisense so far finds everything it should, except the methods of stl classes for example. It really bugs me -.-

Can someone help?

Comment: issue has been fixed with august/september update to visual studio code :)